# Find a new way(velocity) after circle-circle collision

Tags: java, math, physics, algebra

[image: image describes that two circles collide with their velocities.]

I want to know that after the collision, What will be the new direction?
(please, answer with a diagram! formulas making me confused)

Comment: Result depends on physical model. For example, is collision elastic? Are masses distinct?

Comment: yes, Collision is elastic, and masses are the same, I want to the directions of the circles where they are gone in diagrame.

Comment: Belongs on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Are you familiar with the idea of different reference frames (such as the way this collision looks to a moving observer)? Do you know about the Center of Mass frame?

Comment: Yes, I know about the center of mass, but I don't know about where the circle will go after the collision. will you explain with the diagram?

Comment: I can't draw a diagram, but do you know how a circle would bounce off a flat wall? And you see the line you drew tangent to both circles? In the center of mass frame, each circle will bounce off that line, as if it were a wall. (I assume there's no friction-- with friction, the motion is more complicated.)

Comment: thanks!, now I understand little little